# Python: Avoid waiting for a class (with sleep time) to complete before launching a second instance

Tags: python, multithreading, python-class

I have been struggling with this part for quite some time and while there are tutorials on how to pause, there are none on how to bypass them.

Below is a simplified version of the code I am trying to build:

While i was able to use the threadpoolexecutor to initiate both the class instances at the same time, the for loop does not conclude till the second instance(myobjecty), with a wait time of 20s has run through.

The same is true for the "for loop" even in the while True: function.

Basically, I would like the for loop to not hold up the process flow. I have tried using asycnio too, but it doesnt fit well within the class modules.

Thanks

```
import time
import datetime
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, ProcessPoolExecutor


xyz = {'delay': 5, 'name': '5_s_delay'}
xyz1 = {'delay': 20, 'name': '20_s_delay'}

class MyClass():

    def __init__(self, params, **kwargs):
        self.delay = params.get('delay')
        print("delay is: ", self.delay)
        self.name = params.get('name')
        time.sleep(self.delay)
        print(f"end of init function, thread name: {self.name}, {datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')}")

        self.function()

    def function(self):
        print("function initiated \n\n")



if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2)
    myobjectx = executor.submit(MyClass, xyz)
    myobjecty = executor.submit(MyClass, xyz1)


    for each_instance in [myobjectx, myobjecty]:
        print("For loop:", each_instance.result())
        print("For loop:", each_instance.result().name)

    while True:
        for each_instance in [myobjectx, myobjecty]:
            print("\nwhile true loop:", each_instance.result().name, datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
            print("end of for loop")
            time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The `.result()` call will block until the thread has completed. If you want to continue then don't call `.result()` until you have done everything else and want to ensure that the async threads have completed.

Comment: What do you want to happen *instead* of what's happening?

Comment: Thanks Daniel, but in the real code I am building, the While True loop needs information from the `.result()` part. What i would like to do is that whichever of the class instance has completed its process, will pass on to the while true loop.

Comment: @monica, so right now the code pauses till `for each_instance in [myobjectx, myobjecty]:` is completed. What I would like to do is that once `myobjectx` class has completed its process, it should pass on the various calculation results from it under the for each instance loop and continue on to the while true loop without waiting for the `myobjecty` class to complete its round (the 20 second is just a place holder in my code, the objecty has to wait for 120 minutes some time)